# How to do hyperparameter tuning on Sagemaker Scikit Learn container?

Tags: scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to follow and modify [this notebook](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/multi_model_sklearn_home_value/sklearn_multi_model_endpoint_home_value.ipynb) to incorporate hyperparameter tuning rather than simply build a random forest model. But I'm having trouble understanding how to do that. My first issue is: hyperparameters are set in two cells - first in the cell writing `$SCRIPT_FILENAME` where `n_estimators` and `min_samples_leaf` are set to 10 and 3, respectively, and then again in the cell where `launch_training_job()` is defined where they are set to 100 and 3, respectively. Why are they defined twice? When I ran the code, it seemed 100 was used for `n_estimators`, so what was the point of defining it to be 10 earlier?

Second issue, it seems from this [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-adds-scikit-learn-support/) that there is a way to do automatic model tuning. But I don't see examples of how to do this. Can someone share or enlighten me on ways to incorporate hyperparameter tuning into SageMaker Scikit Learn containers?

Answer (score 1):

HPO is a generic feature in SageMaker, it works the same whatever algo or framework you use. Plenty of examples are available here: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/hyperparameter_tuning